# Elasticsearch 5.2.2 :: Deleting an entry in a map field has no effect

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a map field, and I'm trying to update it with a script (Painless). when I execute the script with a rest client it works, but not working with the java API (No change, but the result in the UpdateResponse is "UPDATED"). Anyone can help me resolving this:
Elasticsearch 5.2.2 (Tried also on 5.1.1)

--------- Rest Client (Chrome):

```
POST localhost:9200/context/profile/720c7bc5-9c52-48bd-b281-760f595c6418/_update
BODY :{
    "scriptedUpsert": true,
    "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "inline": "ctx._source.put(\"scores\", params.scoringValue)",
      "params": {
      "scoringValue": {
        "_i833rilwd": 333
      }
    }
}
}
```

--------- Java Client:

```
String script = "ctx._source.put(\"scores\", params.scoringValue)";

//Map where I remove and put to update
Map scores = toRemove.getScores();

HashMap scriptParams = new HashMap<>();
scriptParams.put("scoringValue", scores);

Script actualScript = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", script, scriptParams);

UpdateResponse resp = client.prepareUpdate(index, itemType, itemId).setScript(actualScript)
.execute()
.get();
```

Thx in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about JAVA but i think problem is in

> \"

try this

```
String script = "ctx._source.put(\\"scores\\", params.scoringValue)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by doing a refresh index before the remove, if not there was document version conflicts. Hope this will help.